# DBus error while boot after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: boot-failure, dbus

After upgrading to oneiric, Ubuntu appears to be unable to start dbus correctly, which virtually renders half the system unusable. The startup error seems to happen rather early in the bootstages - and I have not yet figured out where exactly, or even what actually causes it.

I've tried to run dbus manually (`sudo service dbus start`), but no avail. I'm really not sure what could be done.

What are my options? Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu (my /home is not going to be affected, as it's a partion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read post #9 there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/858122

Comment: Thank you, however, I have been able to fix it using this guide: http://joshua14.homelinux.org/blog/?p=1029 - who would have thought that dbus would behave that way? :-(

Answer (score 0):

Boot up in single user mode (recovery mode and pick the "root shell" option from the menu) and do this:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
cd /var
rm -rf run lock
ln -s /run run
ln -s /run/lock lock
reboot
```

That is, change /var/run to a symlink pointing at /run and /var/lock to a symlink pointing at /run/lock. That's the new place they belong. You have to do it in single-user mode when services aren't running, however.

That's supposed to happen during the upgrade/install process, but there's a bug some encounter where it doesn't happen.

More details available behind here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/858122